# Iam getting following error everytime i try to run my proc ...Incorrect syntax near 'END'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_StoredProc_Status] @Procname varchar(50)
AS

BEGIN
    ---- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

    BEGIN TRY
        -- Check if the procedure is already running.
        -- This check is MANDATORY in all stored procs.
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM IMP_StoredProcRunTracking
                WHERE StoredProcName = @Procname
                    AND DATEADD(hh, 1, ISNULL(StartedAt, DATEADD(year, - 50, GETDATE()))) > GETDATE()
                )
            BEGIN
                RETURN
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                MERGE INTO IMP_StoredProcRunTracking AS Target
                USING (
                    SELECT @procname StoredProcName
                    ) AS Source
                    ON Target.StoredProcName = Source.StoredProcName
                WHEN MATCHED
                    THEN
                        UPDATE
                        SET Target.StartedAt = GETDATE()
                WHEN NOT MATCHED
                    THEN
                        INSERT (
                            StoredProcName
                            ,StartedAt
                            )
                        VALUES (
                            @Procname
                            ,GETDATE()
                            );
                        end

    END
```

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because it looks like SQL Server.

Comment: pleas edit the question to explain what you intend this code to do

Comment: And it looks like you're trying to code your own version of sp_getapplock: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `end try`/`begin catch`/`end catch` to actually handle the exception handling that you have started.

Answer (score 1):

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_StoredProc_Status] @Procname varchar(50)
AS

BEGIN
    ---- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

    BEGIN TRY
        -- Check if the procedure is already running.
        -- This check is MANDATORY in all stored procs.
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM IMP_StoredProcRunTracking
                WHERE StoredProcName = @Procname
                    AND DATEADD(hh, 1, ISNULL(StartedAt, DATEADD(year, - 50, GETDATE()))) > GETDATE()
                )
            BEGIN
                RETURN
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                MERGE INTO IMP_StoredProcRunTracking AS Target
                USING (
                    SELECT @procname StoredProcName
                    ) AS Source
                    ON Target.StoredProcName = Source.StoredProcName
                WHEN MATCHED
                    THEN
                        UPDATE
                        SET Target.StartedAt = GETDATE()
                WHEN NOT MATCHED
                    THEN
                        INSERT (
                            StoredProcName
                            ,StartedAt
                            )
                        VALUES (
                            @Procname
                            ,GETDATE()
                            );
                        end


    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.

    END CATCH

END
```

Comment: thanks alot Gordon. I am new to SQL and in beginner phase. Will try no to make such silly mistakes. Thanks alot